# C# LINQ - Comparing to float lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of floats and both with the same size, for example:

```
List<float> list1 = new List<float>{ 2.1, 1.3, 2.2, 6.9 }
List<float> list2 = new List<float>{ 2.5, 3.3, 4.5, 7.8 }
```

Using LINQ I would like to check if all items in list1 are less or equal than those in list2, for example:

2.1 <= 2.5
1.3 <= 3.3
2.2 <= 4.5
6.9 <= 7.8

In this case I want to obtain true as result as all items in list1 are <= items in list2. What is the best efficient way to do it?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the lists are different lengths?

Comment: yes, I want to compare values on same index: list1[0] with list2[0], list1[1] with list2[1], .... also both list always have the same size, in my case it is not possible that lists have different sizes.

Comment: Your collection initializers like `new List<float>{ 2.1, 1.3, 2.2, 6.9 }` won't work because you can't add `double`s to a list of `float`s.

Comment: yes, you are right, but you can do: List<float> list = new List<float>(new float[]{1.2f,3.2f,4.5f});

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want `Zip`, if you *really* want to compare these pairwise. (It's not true to say that all items in `list1` are smaller than all items in `list2`, as 6.9 is greater than 2.5 for example.)

Using [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
bool smallerOrEqualPairwise = list1.Zip(list2, (x, y) => x <= y)
                                   .All(x => x);
```

Or:

```
bool smallerOrEqualPairwise = list1.Zip(list2, (x, y) => new { x, y })
                                   .All(pair => pair.x <= pair.y);
```

The first option is more efficient, but the second is perhaps more readable.

EDIT: As noted in comments, this would be even more efficient, at the possible expense of more readability (more negatives).

```
bool smallerOrEqualPairwise = !list1.Zip(list2, (x, y) => x <= y)
                                    .Contains(false);
```

Comment: Yes, I want to compare them pairwise as commented above in the previous comment, for example, list1[0] <= list2[0], list1[1] <= list2[1] and so on. Instead of x < y is x <= y. Many thanks.

Comment: @user1624552: Right, have fixed the operator.

Comment: If you use `.Contains(false)` instead of `.All(x => x)`, you have one lambda less.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.Zip(list2, (x, y) => new { X = x, Y = y }).
      All(item => (item.X <= item.Y))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool result = Enumerable.Range(0, list1.Count).All(i => list1[i] <= list2[i]);
```